# Как убрать редирект в Laravel на 404 странице?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel5

Здравствуйте. Нужно на странице 404 убрать редирект. Любая страница может открыться как site.ru/page и редикерт будет на site.ru/page/ Это реализовано в контроллере через $this->middleware('redirect'); но нужно что бы 404 открывалась как и пишется, без редиректа - site.ru/page123 так и открывалась, а не как сейчас site.ru/page123/
Код middleware:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{ 
    if (!preg_match('/.+\/$/', $request->getRequestUri()))
    { 
        return Redirect::to( preg_replace("/\s{2,}/",'/', $request->getRequestUri() . "/" ), 301);
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Все это хорошо работает, но на странице 404 это нужно убрать. Если данных нету, то перебрасываем на 404, это делаю так:

```
 if (!$data) {
     App::abort(404);
 }
```

Как можно устранить?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно вас понял, вам нужна отдельная страница 404 а не отображение страницы с ошибкой по неверному маршруту, я делаю это так:

в файле App\Exceptions\Handler

в методе render:

```
if($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException)
                return redirect('/404'));
```

Только не забудьте создать обработку маршрута 404